# Add multiple files to a Zip file using DotNetZip is too slow

Tags: dotnetzip

I followed the example below: (https://dotnetzip.codeplex.com)

```
  String[] filenames = { "ReadMe.txt", "c:\\data\\collection.csv", "c:\\reports\\AnnualSummary.pdf"};
  using (ZipFile zip = new ZipFile())
  {
    zip.CompressionLevel = CompressionLevel.None;
    zip.AddFiles(filenames, "files");
    zip.Save("Archive.zip");
  }
```

But when I add 200 audio files to a zip, it too slow, even copy is faster.
How can I add multiple file to zip is faster ? Another solution or work around ?

Comment: When you zip files, it compresses them. It's not just a simple copy. So it will be slower than copying. There won't be a fast way to zip 200 audio files.

Comment: Hi Relevant, I updated question.

Comment: We don't know what you're trying to accomplish. If you need the files in a zip file, then there's no workaround.